# Vendor prefixed css that deviates from current standard

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

I'm trying to find a resource that has a list of browser specific implementations of CSS properties that deviate from the current W3C standards.

For example, say IE supported something like this:

```
.my-class {
  -ms-foo: fizz buzz;
}
```

but when the proposal became a candidate reccomendation the standardized equivalent was:

```
.my-class {
  foo: buzz fizz;
}
```

In order to support versions of IE released before the CR, I'd want to write:

```
.my-class {
  -ms-foo: fizz buzz;
  foo: buzz fizz;
}
```

Googling for a list of these sorts of changes hasn't been terribly fruitful, there's a lot of wailing and gnashing of teeth around vendor prefixes but not a lot of "gotcha" lists.  Best I've found thus far are [offhand mentions](http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/) of changes (in that case, `-webkit-border-radius`), but those rarely document the actual expected input; they tend to just give a broken example.

I have found an OK [list of the prefixes](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) that exist (along with their standard status), but unfortunately it doesn't give the kind of details necessary for spotting the changes I'm interested in.

#### So, do any such lists exist?

I'll take partial lists, or ones that exclude really old browsers (don't really care about IE6, for example).  I'm also only really concerned about the big 3.1 browsers (IE, Firefox, Webkit/Chrome/Safari, and <sub>Opera</sub>).

I also care about things that haven't been addressed by the W3C (like [appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-appearance)), this is a hard enough problem without worrying about the things vendors have straight-up made up.

Comment: How long before casperOne sees and closes this?

Comment: @BoltClock 42 seconds...

Comment: Actually, the version that deviated *drastically* from the standard was [`-moz-border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-radius), not `-webkit-border-radius` (which was much closer)

Comment: @BoltClock alright, now I've got 2...  The thought of having to grab about 30 browser versions and brute forcing this is terrifying.

Comment: And that is why I hate vendor prefixes.

Comment: If it's useful at all, WebMatrix uses three XML files to supply the IDE with vendor prefixes. I could post those to a Dropbox somewhere if you don't mind looking at XML.

Comment: @TiesonT. if there's information about how the values should differ that'd be useful, if it's just a list of prefixed properties then not so much.

Comment: i wonder if [this CSS Prefixer site](http://cssprefixer.appspot.com/) might help?  Not sure how smart or expansive his code is, but it might account for the browser-specific differences.

Comment: @Leland looks like it's got *some* [smarts](https://github.com/myfreeweb/cssprefixer/blob/master/cssprefixer/rules.py#L247).

Comment: @KevinMontrose Not really - it's mostly just data for the Intellisense tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an exhaustive list out there, but based on [Compass](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3), [CSSPrefixer](https://github.com/myfreeweb/cssprefixer/blob/master/cssprefixer/rules.py), and [this list](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) from Peter Beverloo here's what I can scrape together.

#### background-clip

`-moz-background-clip` accepts `padding` and `border` instead of `padding-box` and `border-box`
`-webkit-background-clip` behaves the same as the -moz version, but also accepts `content` instead of `content-box`

#### background-origin

`-moz` and `-webkit` versions accept the same values as their `background-clip` equivalents

#### background-size

`-webkit-background-size` duplicates single values, so `-webkit-background-size: 10px` is equivalent to `background-size: 10px 10px`.  The prefixed webkit equivalent of `background-size:10px` is `-webkit-background-size: 10px auto;`.

#### border-radius and friends

The `-moz` equivalents of `border-top-left-radius`, `border-bottom-left-radius`, etc. are `-moz-border-radius-topleft`, `-moz-border-radius-bottomleft` and so on.

`-webkit-border-radius` differs from the final spec in it's handling of the two value shorthand.  Webkit treats it as if all the long form versions were passed two values.

More concretely:

`-webkit-border-radius: 1px 2px` is equivalent to

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1px 2px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1px 2px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1px 2px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1px 2px;
```

while `border-radius: 1px 2px` is equivalent to

```
border-top-left-radius: 1px;
border-top-right-radius: 2px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
```

The only work around I know of for this is to expand the two value case of `-webkit-border-radius` into it's long forms so as to match proper `border-radius`.

#### display

If you want `diplay:box` to work everywhere, you need to use prefixed values like so:

```
display:-webkit-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:box;
```

I have no idea why this is, as all the box model specific properties (like [box-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-align)) also have prefixed versions in those browsers.

---

Note that this doesn't include anything that's not currently part of a W3C document, like [appearance](https://github.com/myfreeweb/cssprefixer/blob/master/cssprefixer/rules.py), even if multiple browsers support it.

Answer (score 2):

I find CSS3Info useful: http://www.css3.info/preview/ (**edited** - sorry, this is what I meant to post originally).

**EDIT:** Hmm. I'm batting zero today. I could have sworn there was more on browser prefixes on that site...

Comment: @KevinMontrose Yeah, sorry, I double-checked it, and the only properties it really shows prefixes for are `box-shadow` and `border-radius`. Bring on the down-votes... :p

Answer (score 1):

Deviations from the standards are not uncommon (i.e. rendering quirks) but deviations from the standard/proposed notation are fairly rare imho, this resource should do the trick:

caniuse.com normally provides good external links in resources section, e.g. for [border-radius](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) it linked to [`-webkit` differences](http://www.css3files.com/border/#vbl3) and [this exhaustive rendering overview](http://muddledramblings.com/table-of-css3-border-radius-compliance/)